# Adding TEXT under the 3 Bars?

Tags: mmenu

I want to add the word MENU under the 3 bars to make it more clear to visitors what those bars are - how do I do that? Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that opens/closes the menu is just wrapped in a standard a tag, so you can put anything you want into the a tag.

```
<a href="#menu"></a>
```

can become:

```
<a href="#menu"><img src="mymenubutton.jpg"></a>
```

And you can create your own menu icon or button here, to look however you want.

Or you can add an click event to your own div:

```
<div id="openmymenu">Click me to open menu</div>

$("#openmymenu").click(function() {
  $("#menu").data("mmenu").open();
});
```

And then put any text and/or images you want inside your div.